# mpi4py recv data cap?

Tags: python, mpi4py

I am working on a program that is communication intensive with a group of people. I'm not particularly good at debugging distributed programs, but I have a strong suspicion that I am sending too many messages at once to a process. I have reimplemented the actor model in mpi4py. Each process has a "mailbox" of jobs and when they finish with their mailbox they decide to go into `CHECK_FOR_UPDATES` mode, where they see if there is any new messages they can receive.

I had issues with the program that a group of students and I have been working on. When the load became too big it would start to crash, but we couldn't figure out where the issue was because we're all pretty bad at debugging stuff.

I asked some people at my school if he had any ideas and suggested that, as we are reimplementing the actor system, we should consider using Akka. A student this year said that there may still be a problem, that one actor may get inundated with messages and crash. [I asked about it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216930/resending-a-dead-letter-in-akka) The stream model seems not to be what we want (see my comment for more details) and I have since then looked back at the mpi4py program as I had not accounted for this problem before.

In the plain C or Fortran implementation, it appears that there is a [`count` parameter for `MPI_Recv`](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Recv.html). I noticed that `comm.recv` has no `count` parameter and suspect that when a process goes into `CHECK_FOR_UPDATES` mode it just consume a ton of messages from a variety of sources and dies. (Technically, I don't know for sure, but we suspect it might be the case.) Is there a way to cap the amount of data `comm.recv` accepts?

(Note: I want to avoid using `comm.Recv` variant as it restricts the user to using `numpy` arrays.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Found the answer:](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html)

> The `recv()` and `irecv()` methods may be passed a buffer object that can be repeatedly used to receive messages avoiding internal memory allocation. **The buffer must be sufficiently large to accomodate the transmitted messages**.

Emphasis mine. Therefore, I have to use `Send` and `Recv`.